# Choosing a random number from an array and returning it to a label

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program that allows users to input genes and randomly chooses a weighted option.

For example:

```
// If statements for gene 1 (NNN)
if (intSireBuild == 1)
{
    if (intDamBuild == 1)
    {
        lblResults1.Content = "NNN";
    }
}
else if (intSireBuild == 1)
{
    if (intDamBuild == 2)
    {
        // Random number thing

        int[] NNNxNna;
        NNNxNna = new int[5];

        NNNxNna[0] = 1;
        NNNxNna[1] = 1;
        NNNxNna[2] = 1;
        NNNxNna[3] = 1;
        NNNxNna[4] = 2;
        NNNxNna[5] = 2;

        Random random = new Random();
        int gene2 = random.Next(NNNxNna.Length);

        // The problem is occurring here, I believe

        if (gene2 == 1)
        {
            lblResults1.Content = "NNN";
        }
        else
        {
            lblResults1.Content = "Nna";
        }
    }
}
// When you click the button, a calculation will be made using user inputed genes
```

I realize that there is most likely a simpler way to do this, but this is the way I'd like to do it.

The issue that I'm having is that somwehere between the array that carries a list of numbers (1,1,1,1,2,2,) (meant so that the gene 'NNN - or '1'' is more common than than 'Nna'), what's happening, is that the program gets confused and doesn't output any information to the label that I'm using.

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out what I'm missing / not coding correctly?

Comment: you have forgotten to pick one of the items in array at a random index.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following will never happen otherwise it would have enter the first "if"

```
else if (intSireBuild == 1)
```

You should have remove the second condition and leaving it with the following

```
if (intSireBuild == 1)
{
    if (intDamBuild == 1)
    {
        lblResults1.Content = "NNN";
    }
    else if (intDamBuild == 2)
    {
        // Random number thing
        // Rest of the code
```

**Additionally**, this is incorrect bound index `NNNxNna[5] = 2;` because array with a size of 5 can only have indices between 0 to 4.

Comment: Thank you that fixed my problem!